# What does 'friend' do in Obj c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on a project where I have created a class named Friend and just noticed that Xcode colors it like a keyword or a modifier. Can I use it like I did in my code, or it has other purpose?

[image]

Updated:
It seems this is already answered here:

[Why does the xcode IDE think `friend` is a reserved-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362912/why-does-the-xcode-ide-think-friend-is-a-reserved-word)

But thanks for the help guys!

Comment: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/813-friend-functions-and-classes/

Comment: Refer This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052450/c-class-with-objective-c-friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ provides the friend keyword to do just this. Inside a class, you can indicate that other classes (or simply functions) will have direct access to protected and private members of the class. When granting access to a class, you must specify that the access is granted for a class using the class keyword:

**friend class aClass;**

Note that friend declarations can go in either the public, private, or protected section of a class--it doesn't matter where they appear. In particular, specifying a friend in the section marked protected doesn't prevent the friend from also accessing private fields.

Answer (score 1):

`friend` is a keyword used in `C++`, for creating friend functions.
Objective C supports both C and C++ keywords, so it is better to rename that parameter.

More about friend functions : [friend function in C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_function)